# Excel VBA Delete empty rows in table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table `tabelaClientes` in Sheet "`Clientes`" and I want to delete the rows where the field "`Nome`" is empty.

How do I do that?

This is what I'm trying:

```
Sub Cliente()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim row As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Clientes")

For Each row In ws.[tabelaClientes[Nome]].Rows
     If row.Value = "" Then
        row.Delete
    End If
Next

Exit Sub
```

But this is deleting only some of the rows where `Nome` is empty, not all, why?

Comment: **You need to run the loop backwards.** *(from the bottom of the table to the top of the table*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent thanks, is that possible with a for each loop?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I've never been taught how to do it that way. Can you please point me to somewhere I can learn about it. Thanks!

Comment: The reason it deletes only some rows: If your data is `Nome1, blank, blank, Nome2` then the "For" row goes from 1 to 4. Row 2 gets deleted. Then for Row 3, the data is `Nome1, blank, Nome2, ..` so row3 is not blank. Doing `For iRow = high to low step -1` does not have that problem. (+1 to @Alexandre P. Levasseur).

Comment: what if you instead do `row = row.previous` followed by `row.next.delete` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a very simple call to SpecialCells() to do that instead of using a loop.

```
Range("tabelaClientes[Nome]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Edit: To expand on my answer because I was in a hurry. SpecialCells mimic the menu that you will find in Excel after having pressed F5 and selected "Special cells... Blanks". This has the advantage of selecting all blanks at the same time and then delete the rows. Iteration can be very slow if your table is getting large thus this way will save a lot of time.

It does seem that you cannot delete multiple non-contiguous rows in a *table*. You can do either one of two things:

1- Convert back the table to a range and change the reference to a standard excel reference

2- Loop through the results of SpecialCells().

Option #2 will yield in slower code because of the loop but it will still be better than looping through all cells and check if they are blank but I can understand that you may need to keep it as a table.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. However, I get the error: 'Run-time error 1004: Delete method of class range failed' when the blanks are non-contiguous